# ¿Porque no funciona mi codigo para manipular elementos del DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Quiero hacer que cuando presione cualquier tecla el tamaño de la letra aumente pero no sucede eso
El siguiente codigo es:

```js
function cambiarTamañoFuente(event) {
  const div = event.target;
  const nuevoTamañoFuente = "24px";
  div.style.fontSize = nuevoTamañoFuente;
}
const dic = document.getElementById("parra2");
dic.addEventListener("keydown", cambiarTamañoFuente);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicios js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parra2">Hola Mundo 2</div>
    <button type="button" id="calc" >Presiona</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El elemento id seleccionado hace referencia a un parrafo con el texto en mi html, no logro poder hacer que ejecute los cambios presionando cualquier letra , si me ayudan a poder hacerlo funcionar estare agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Tu `div` nunca adquiere el foco, por lo tanto el evento `keydown` nunca se ejecuta dentro de él.

Para que adquiera el foco basta con agregar `tabindex="0"` al HTML

Ejemplo:

```js
function cambiarTamañoFuente(event) {
  const div = event.target;
  const nuevoTamañoFuente = "24px";
  div.style.fontSize = nuevoTamañoFuente;
}
const dic = document.getElementById("parra2");
dic.addEventListener("keydown", cambiarTamañoFuente);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicios js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parra2" tabindex="0">Hola Mundo 2</div>
    <button type="button" id="calc" >Presiona</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```